# For easy shell MySQL (Mariadb) access the "_my.cnf" file does not work

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I've installed a recent version of MariaDB on my CentOS 8:

`mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.5.8-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1`

Given that I've changed the root password to something more complex, I'd like to not have to type it every time I SSH into the server and access this file. So I've created a `_my.cnf` file in my own user's /root folder:

```
[client]
user="root"
password="PASS" 

[mysqldump]
user="root"
password="PASS"
```

However, this doesn't seem to work anymore. With this in place I expect to only write "mysql" at the command prompt and it would know to find the user and the password.

It's not working this way. Any ideas on what step I'm missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Where have you read that the filename should be called `_my.cnf`?

Comment: Some old remnant from older servers, I think. Could it be a Cpanel type thing? Would love to know how to automate...perhaps an alias in .bashrc? Or should the file name be different?

Comment: Check https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/option-files.html for valid locations for the mysql configuration files. It should be `.my.cnf` or even better use `.mylogin.cnf` (see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-config-editor.html).

Comment: Very helpful, thank you. If this was an answer I'd accept it. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

As helpfully mentioned by Progman, the filename should be `.my.cnf`.